# Where can I find my credentials for putting in a SQL server connection string?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, connection-string

I am currently using asp.net mvc5 where I am following a tutorial. However I have got to a point of the tutorial where it asks me to enter in a connection string

```
<add name="CountryConnectionString" connectionString="data source=server name,1436;database=Sample;user id=sa;password=123456;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

It asks to enter my own credentials but unfortunately I don't think I have ever set a username and password is there a way of finding out? Apologies if this is a silly question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need to install [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express) to create a SQL Server Intance and your ConnectionString should be like:

```
<add name="CountryConnectionString" connectionString="data source=CathyServer;database=CathyDataBase;user id=sa;password=123456;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

In the installation of SQLServer Express the installer ask for those names, and you should be able to change or keep, in the "Next" SQL Server Instalation an exmple should be:

```
<add name="CountryConnectionString" connectionString="data source=localhost;database=WhateverName;user id=sa;password=123456;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

**Edited:**

Ok, in yout Solution Explorer (Maybe hided on right), in the folder App_Data should have a .mdf file named Sample, if you doble click on it (.mdf file) in the left, in server explorer you can see your Data Connections if you right click on your Data Connection (Maybe called, Sample) select Properties and you can see at your right the properties of Sample.mdf in the Connection Section and field Connection String looks like:

`Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="c:\users\mmendozat\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\App_Data\MyDatabase.mdf";Integrated Security=True`

connectionString=" **Copy this and put here** "

Comment: You don't need SQL Server Express if you've got the Visual Studio data tools installed. With something like LocalDB, you don't need credentials, since it's integrated security. After your create the database in Visual Studio, you can simply view the properties on the database and copy the connection string from there.

Comment: If she is learning from the basic, she should learn "the correct way". I think learn with a Database Administrator like SQLSExpress  it's the best way to see what is she doing.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I thought I did not SQL server express alright. But when I right click on the database and go in to properties it just shows the details I have put in the connection string?

Answer (score -1):

You can get the solution with the use of integrated security like the below code

```
<add name="ConnectionStringName"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"/>
```

**Integrated Security (synonym: Trusted_Connection)**

This setting specifies whether the connection should use the user ID and password in the connection string to log on to the SQL Server instance, or the current Windows account credentials should be used for authentication:

**True** means use Windows integrated security to log in to SQL Server, even if the connection string includes User ID and Password settings.

**False** means use SQL Server security to log in by using the User ID and Password values in the connection string, and raise an exception if they are not present.

**SSPI (Security Support Provider Interface)** means use Windows Security if User ID and Password are absent, and use SQL Server security if they are present.

Useful link:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx